# How to configure PyCharm to wrap lines in a sensible way

Tags: coding-style, pycharm

I cannot be certain, but it seems that I have inadvertedly reset some setting (or there has been a buggish feature in an update to PyCharm), but it seems that the current version seems to wrap to long lines in an undesirable way:

E.g, consider that this:

```
this.trainwreck.is.too.long.to.fit.on.a.single.line.foo.bar.do_something\
    (snakes, 
     planes,
     samuel,
     jackson)
```

Which is just, well, pretty-much brain dead, since both

```
this.trainwreck.is.too.long.to.fit.on.a.single.line.foo.bar.do_something(
    snakes, planes, samuel, jackson)
```

and

```
this.trainwreck.is.too.long.to.fit.on.a.single.line.foo.bar.do_something(
    snakes,
    planes,
    samuel,
    jackson)
```

would make much more sense. Is there a setting to fix this, because I'm pretty sure that this wasn't broken when I was running version 2.5.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like a bug, [reported at YouTrack](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-7230), please star/vote to receive notifications on progress.